# Installation of bioconductor in R

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor

I am having some trouble installing the bioconductor package in R, it is hanging at the "testing if installed packages can be loaded" part

```
    source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    #Installing package into ‘/homexxx/lib/R’
    #(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    #trying URL 'http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/src/contrib/BiocInstaller_1.10.2.tar.gz'
    #Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13424 bytes (13 Kb)     
    #opened URL
    #==================================================
    #downloaded 13 Kb
    #
    #* installing *source* package ‘BiocInstaller’ ...
    #** R
    #** inst
    #** preparing package for lazy loading
    #** help
    #*** installing help indices
    #** building package indices
    #** testing if installed package can be loaded
    #^C
    #No traceback available
    #* removing ‘/home/xxx/lib/R/BiocInstaller’
    #
    #The downloaded source packages are in
    #        ‘/tmp/Rtmpb2nVhP/downloaded_packages’
    #'biocLite.R' failed to install 'BiocInstaller', use
    #  'install.packages("BiocInstaller",
    #  repos="http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc")'
```

Here is R version:

```
R --version
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

Comment: Did you try to run `install.packages("BiocInstaller", repos="http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc")` as was suggested by the error message?

Comment: I tried that, same result.

Comment: When I try to install it this is what I get:  package ‘BiocInstaller’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0) maybe it is not available for version 3.0.1 either

Comment: source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") seems to work fine in R 3.0.0

Comment: I am running R 3.0.1 on Ubuntu and could install the package without problems too.

Comment: @R_Newbie probably you mean you tried `install.packages("BiocInstaller", repos="http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc")` but that is tailored to the version of R used by CravingSpirit. You would just do the usual `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite()`

Comment: @CravingSpirit it's not really helpful to cross-post here and on the Bioconductor [mailing list[(https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/attachments/20130625/84d4bbc9/attachment.pl); look on the mailing list for help.

Comment: @MartinMorgan you are totally right, I used source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") and I was able to install the package. Thanks!